# axes don't match array / size mismatch, m1: [132096 x 344], m2: [118336 x 128]

Tags: matrix, plot, pytorch, tensor, autoencoder

This is a linear auto-encoder code, the original picture is 344*344 RGB, after the training process is over, I want to show the decoded picture using the code below, but it has ValueError: axes don't match array

pytorch, google colab(GPU)

```
enter code here:
EPOCH = 20
BATCH_SIZE = 128
LR = 0.005  # learning rate


torch.cuda.empty_cache()
data_transforms = torchvision.transforms.Compose([
    torchvision.transforms.RandomResizedCrop(344),
    torchvision.transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()])
path1 = 'drive/My Drive/Colab/image/test/'
train_data = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(path1, 
transform=data_transforms)


train_loader = Data.DataLoader(dataset=train_data, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
shuffle=True)


class AutoEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AutoEncoder, self).__init__()

        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(3*344*344, 128),
            nn.Tanh(), # 激活
            nn.Linear(128, 64),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(64, 12),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(12, 3),   # compress to 3 features which can be 
visualized in plt
        )
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(3, 12),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(12, 64),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(64, 128),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(128, 3*344*344),
            nn.Sigmoid(),       # compress to a range (0, 1)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)

        encoded = self.encoder(x)
        decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
        return encoded, decoded


autoencoder = AutoEncoder()

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(autoencoder.parameters(), lr=LR)
loss_func = nn.MSELoss()


for epoch in range(EPOCH):
    for step, (x, b_label) in enumerate(train_loader):
        b_x = x.view(-1, 3*344*344)   # batch x, shape (batch, 28*28)
        b_y = x.view(-1, 3*344*344)   # batch y, shape (batch, 28*28)

        encoded, decoded = autoencoder(b_x)

        loss = loss_func(decoded, b_y)      # mean square error
        optimizer.zero_grad()               # clear gradients for this 
training step
        loss.backward()                     # backpropagation, compute 
gradients
        optimizer.step()                    # apply gradients


###################################################
######## below is used to plot decoded pic ######## 


with torch.no_grad():
   for img, label in train_loader :
    fig = plt.figure()

)
    imggg = np.transpose(img[0],(1,2,0))
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
    ax1.imshow(imggg)

    if torch.cuda.is_available():
      img = Variable(img.to())
    else:
      img = Variable(img)

    encoded, decoded = autoencoder(img)

    decodeddd = np.transpose(decoded.cpu()[0],(1,2,0))

    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
    ax2.imshow(decodeddd)
```

I expect the output of 2 pics but now only the original one shows, the decoded one doesn't show.

The training process works well, but I don't know what's the problem with picture's size.

Comment: are you sure the input image at test time is 344*344*3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`decoder` is returning a linear output of shape `BATCH_SIZE x 355008`. First, we need to reshape the second dimension to 3 dimensions of shape `3 x 344 x 344` before applying transpose on it. Replacing `decodeddd` with following should do the trick:

```
decodeddd = np.transpose(decoded.cpu()[0].view(3, 344, 344),(1,2,0))
```

Comment: Thank you, my picture presence problem in now solved. May I ask you another question?  after training my model, the decoded picture is completely grey(or sometimes green), is it learning rate problem? Or can you help me with my network? I don't know if there is anything wrong with it.

Comment: did you try multiplying your output picture with 255 before displaying/saving it?

Comment: the idea is that, RGB input to model should be normalized by dividing each by pixel value by 255 and output image should be multiplied with 255 to get values in RGB range (0,255).

Comment: I think nn.Sigmoid()  compress to a range (0, 1) and imshow() can be either value in  (0,255) or float number in (0,1)